# How to remove null values and get row from values from table

Tags: sql

Please help me with the task below. I have table a with four columns
col1,col2,col3 and col4. I want to retrieve from these columns, removing nulls.

So, if my table has

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-----+------+------+-----
A    | B    |  NULL| NULL
C    | D    |  NULL| NULL
NULL | NULL |  E   | F
NULL | NULL |  G   | H
```

I want result to be

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-----+------+------+-----
A    | B    | E    | F  
C    | D    | G    | H
```

Comment: Please explain the rules for the combination.  And, remember that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no concept of next or previous, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: hi Gordon, if col3 is null, is there chance to loop to check other row value and get. ex. my example col3 first is null and can i get third row value. which is not null.

Comment: You need something that determines why E/F are chosen to go with A/B, and not G/H; what if rows 3&4 were G/F  and E/H, would you get ABGF or ABEH?

Comment: @Sahul . . . There is no "third" row, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  (You didn't seem to understand that the first time I wrote it.)

Comment: @SqlACID, Yes. You are right. I want output like this.

Comment: if G/F and E/H means ABGH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.  I have used the analytic ROW_NUMBER() to synthesize a key for joining the rows.  The join is full outer in order to cater for unequal assignments of nulls and values.

```
with cte as (select * from t23)
   , a as ( select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) as rn
            from cte
            where col1 is not null )
   , b as ( select col2, row_number() over (order by col2) as rn
            from cte
            where col2 is not null )            
   , c as ( select col3, row_number() over (order by col3) as rn
            from cte
            where col3 is not null )            
   , d as ( select col4, row_number() over (order by col4) as rn
            from cte
            where col4 is not null )            
select a.col1
       , b.col2
       , c.col3
       , d.col4
from a
     full outer join b
          on a.rn = b.rn
     full outer join c
          on a.rn = c.rn
     full outer join d
          on a.rn = d.rn
/
```

The [SQL Fiddle is for Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62063/1), but this solution will work for any flavour of database which supports a ranking analytic function.  The common table expression is optional, it just makes the other sub-queries easier to write.